# How to reload/ refresh a table after adding new data to database table?

Tags: java, rapidclipse

I use rapidClipse 4.0
And I am at beginning with rapidClipse and java

I created a page with a table and a fieldgroup.
After saving a new record, the table gets not refreshed.
The Properties:
 
AutoQueryData is false
Data is "findAllContacts" (JPASQL Query)
Entity is set.
All col's are set

I tried to follow the video "RapidClipse: Daten manuell laden"
I followed: https://www.rapidclipse.com/en/forum/index.php/forum/programmierung/495-table-refresh-bei-neuem-datensatz

and
https://www.rapidclipse.com/en/forum/index.php/forum/bugs/120-aktualisierung-anzeige-tabelle
---> This Method is not available/undifined

I tried use 
- `this.table.getBeanContainerDatasource().refresh()`
- `this.table.getBeanContainerDatasource().addAll(new OkmMetaDataValueDAO().findAllContacts();` --> This did fill the table a second time/twice with the same data,but did not reload it.
- `this.table.addContainerDatasource().addAll(...` 

to reload the Container
All without success.
 

I feel, that I have to trigger a content reload at the client, by using java-script. but how to do it with rapidclipse?

Could someone explain, what I have to consider/ think about or what I did wrong?

All help would be appreciated! 
Thank you in advance - OpaHeinz

Answer (score 0):

this.table.getBeanContainerDatasource().refresh() 
Always works for me (which you already did).

Note: Some time it take time to have affect in Database and then the view.

In my case, I had this problem. I had to delete the data and refresh the table as soon as data gets deleted. What I found was the time lag. So I placed one more button beside delete button. When someone delete data the "Delete" button gets disabled and refresh button gets enable, the only way to enable "delete" button is to click on refresh.

Comment: important hint which I had not in mind! real good idea!
Thank you very much